# set background color of class while scrolling and also the class is must in fixed position

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I need to change the background color of class(backwhitemarq) while scrolling and also the class backwhitemarq is must fixed position?

**html code:**

```
<div class="backwhitemarq">
 /*i need to change the background color for this class.*/
 <center> offer of the day</center>
</div>
```

**css code:**

```
.backwhitemarq
{
   background-color: #f6e454;
   padding: 3px;
   border-radius: 3px;
   height: 44px;
   margin-top: 15px;
   position:fixed;   //fixed
   width:100%;
   z-index:100;
}
.spacewww     /*another class for background color*/
{
   background-color:green;
}
```

**javascript code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(window).scroll(function()   /*scroll function for window*/
 {  
     var speedscr =$('backwhitemarq'),
     scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

     if (scroll >= 10)
     {
        speedscr.addClass("spacewww");
     } else 
     {
        speedscr.removeClass("spacewww");
    }
 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$(window).scroll(function()   /*scroll function for window*/
 {  
  var speedscr =$('.backwhitemarq');
     var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 10)
    {
       speedscr.addClass("spacewww");
    } else 
    {
        speedscr.removeClass("spacewww");
    }
 });
```

```css
body{ height: 10000px; }
  .backwhitemarq
{
background-color: #f6e454;
padding: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
height: 44px;
margin-top: 15px;
position:fixed;   //fixed
width:100%;
z-index:100;
}
.spacewww     /*another class for background color*/
{
background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="backwhitemarq">/*i need to change the background color for this class.*/
 <center> offer of the day</center>
  </div>
```

I think you forgot to add .(dot) in jquery selector

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(window).scroll(function()   /*scroll function for window*/
 {  
  var speedscr =$('.backwhitemarq'),
     scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 10)
    {
       speedscr.addClass("spacewww");
    } else 
    {
        speedscr.removeClass("spacewww");
    }
 });
  </script>
```

Comment: you also set the height of body so it can be scroll

Comment: Thank you hameed :)